# Starting a cutom-named saved session in KDE

Tags: kubuntu, kde, session

KDE supports saving sessions with arbitrary names. This can be accomplished by using the command `saveCurrentSessionAs`. For example, to save a session called 'session01', we execute

```
DISPLAY=:0.0 qdbus org.kde.ksmserver /KSMServer org.kde.KSMServerInterface.saveCurrentSessionAs "session01"
```

Then `session01` will appear in the list returned by

```
DISPLAY=:0.0 qdbus org.kde.ksmserver /KSMServer org.kde.KSMServerInterface.sessionList
```

as follows:

```
default
session01
saved by user
saved at previous logout
```

The content of all these saved sessions can be seen in `$HOME/.config/ksmserverrc`, which in particular will contain the lines

```
[Session: session01]
clientId1=102221941cd1ac000155588720400000011540004
clientId10=102221941cd1ac000155604496400000011810016
```

etc.

I would like to make the system assume the state described in `session01`.

I know of a hack to do it. I can manually overwrite, in the `$HOME/.config/ksmserverrc` file, the text corresponding to the `saved by user` session by the text corresponding to the `session01` session. Now assume I have set up my system so that on login it restores the manually saved session (how to do that is described in the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/634148/942168) to this question: [Save session settings in KDE environment without shutting down](https://askubuntu.com/questions/633318/save-session-settings-in-kde-environment-without-shutting-down)). Then on the next login,  KDE will restore the state in `saved by user`—which of course will, after my hack, be identical to the state in `session01`.

This can be done through a script. Indeed, I believe this, more or less, *has* been done through a script, namely [this old script](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/477708-manually-saving-restoring-KDE-sessions) from 2012 (look for the function `sessionRestore`).

But I am wondering if there is a way to do this without hacking. (The author of the script I just mentioned agrees that the script is *a hack (not a solution)*—see the end of [this page](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/477031-kde-how-save-more-than-1-session-choose-one-login)). Here, then, is my question:

> Is there a 'non-hacky' way of making my system assume the state saved in `session01`? In other words, is there a specific KDE command or a setting that will load that session, by name? And if there isn't, then what is the point of having `saveCurrentSessionAs` command?

(For what it's worth, I'm running KDE Plasma Version 5.12.7 on kubuntu 18.04.)